# Print datagrid without style -Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have added some styles to my datagrid, I dont want that styles When I print that datagrid .Can you suggest some ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

a) create new sprite, skin it as you like (if you don't want skin, only do the labels), and copy data to it, and print that.
b) override skin for the time of printing, with your own. normal CSS.